# Read an XML file with HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to pass an HTML instruction inside an XML file like this:

```
<modal>
    <content>
            <![CDATA[
                <form id="company-form" name="modal-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">Company name:</label>
                            <input class='form-control' id='usr' type='text'/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">Item name:</label>
                            <input class='form-control' id='usr' type='text'/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            ]]>
    </content>
</modal>
```

And then in a XSL file I want to transform the content into HTML again. I'm doing it as follow:

```
<xsl:value-of select="modal/content" />
```

But the HTML instructions are being passed as a String. Can you guys tell me waht I'm missing?

Comment: How about using XHTML or namespaced HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XSLT processor does support it(e.g. Firefox XSLT doesn't do it), add the attribute `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to your `xsl:value-of` so that it looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="modal/content" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

The output will contain all the HTML code unescaped as desired.